# How to get info that Revit custom export of a view is canceled

Tags: revit-api, revit

I have used Revit custom export of a model for exporting a 3D View based on IExportContext. It works fine. But I found that the export process can be **Canceled** (see screen below)
[Custom export canceling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvknW.png)
Then appears a dialog
[Dialog screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7l7z.png)
I have 2 questions:

1. How to get info that exporting was canceled?
2. Why the name of operation is **Printing** (see [Dialog screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7l7z.png))

Thanks Jeremy for provided solution in Revit 2021.
ViewsExportedByContext works but only in the 2021 version.

Application.ViewsExportedByContext += Application_ViewsExportedByContext;

```
private void Application_ViewsExportedByContext(object sender, ViewsExportedByContextEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Status == RevitAPIEventStatus.Failed)
    {
        // Export was cancelled
    }
```

UPDATE:
We have found the solution for Revit lower 2021.
There is the event in UIApplication:
public event `EventHandler<Autodesk.Revit.UI.Events.DialogBoxShowingEventArgs> DialogBoxShowing`

The idea is simple: if the Cancellation dialog appears and then the method of interface IExportContext
`RenderNodeAction OnElementBegin(ElementId elementId)`
was called, that means the user selected "NO" in cancellation dialog or other dialog appeared. But if the method of interface IExportContext
`void Finish()`
was called that means user selected "YES" in cancellation dialog.

Answer (score 0):

1. Implement and handle the [`IExportContext`
   `IsCanceled` method](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/31f0b662-81a1-89b8-ab2a-0de99af3b753.htm).
2. Because the custom export is in fact a printing or exporting context, cf. the [`CustomExporter` documentation](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/d2437433-9183-cbb1-1c67-dedd86db5b5a.htm): *The Export method of this class triggers standard rendering or exporting process in Revit, but instead of displaying the result on screen or printer, the output is channeled through the given custom context that handles processing of the geometric as well as non-geometric information*.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, your answer is very helpful, as always.